Do we have to assume here that each person walks at a constant speed?
Ralph and Stephanie are two friends who set out to visit one another. They both leave their houses at the same time and walk along the same road.
However, they pass one another without noticing. 1 minute after them crossing paths, Ralph is at Stephanie's house and 4 minutes after the meeting, Stephanie is at Ralph's house.
After how many minutes of walking did their paths cross?

My question is, do we have to assume that both of them walked at a constant speed or can we get a solution without assuming that they walked at a constant speed?

I ask because the following solution of mine is assuming them walking at a constant speed and I can't think of a solution that doesn't use this assumption. Here's my solution:

Let's call Ralph's house as R, Stephanie's house as S and the point they cross paths, M. Also, let's say that they crossed paths after x minutes.

This means that

Speed of Ralph = (distance between R and M)/x 
Speed of Stephanie = (distance between R and M)/4 
Therefore, Speed of Ralph/Speed of Stephanie = 4/x - (Equation 1)

This also means that

Speed of Ralph = (distance between M and S)/1 
Speed of Stephanie = (distance between M and S)/x 
Therefore, Speed of Ralph/Speed of Stephanie = x - (Equation 2

Equation 1 = Equation 2 
4/x = x 
Therefore, x = 2.
From the Russian science magazine, Kvant.

You need to know they walked at a constant speed. Otherwise, change the first part of the walk (before they cross) to really slow but leave the second part unchanged.

@Lucenaposition , can you please explain further this line, "Otherwise, change the first part of the walk (before they cross) to really slow but leave the second part unchanged. " ?

@Lucenaposition , can you pls give an example of how making their speeds non-uniform will result in a different answer?

Maybe it took them both $x$ minutes to walk halfway, then 1 minute later Ralph arrived then 4 minutes later Stephanie arrived.

@Lucenaposition , all this^ is already mentioned in the question.  What's your point? Possible for you to create an answer giving a general proof as well as providing an example which shows that not assuming that they walk at a constant speed will result in a different answer.

An assumption needs to be made regarding the relation between their speed before and after the meeting point, otherwise there is no unique answer since otherwise we can make them stop (or be very slow, effectively same as stop but non-zero) at some point along the road for arbitrary duration before the meeting point, and this changes the value of x without changing the 1 minute and 4 minute post-meeting time. In other words, there is no unique answer if we don't assume
Note that there is still a unique answer even if the speed before and after the meeting is different, as long as we know the relation between the before and after speed.
For example, assuming Ralph's speed post-meeting is N times his speed pre-meeting, your equations become:

4/x = N.x
x = sqrt(4/N)

So you can change the answer by changing the assumption of the ratio of Ralph speed before and after the meeting.
Assuming constant speed all the way (N=1) is the simplest assumption, and is common in this type of puzzles, so it seems to be what's intended.
